# How to set types within the function body on loop

Tags: typescript

I am creating a function that wraps some logic, and I am dealing with a third party library function that will take my input and return a generic function.

the returned generic function from `some3rdPartyLibraryMethod` is always based on what parameters I provide to it.

I have the following code:

```
interface Endpoints {
  [k: string]: (queryParams?: string) => void
}
function XYZ<T extends Endpoints>(obj: T) {
  type Queries = { [key: string]: any }
  const generatedQueries: Queries = {}
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    generatedQueries[key] = some3rdPartyLibraryMethod(val)
  }
  return generatedQueries
}
```

Currently, in my code, I am setting the type Queries values as `any`. I want to change that, to be the actual returned type of each iteration on this `some3rdPartyLibraryMethod`.

when I hover my cursor on `some3rdPartyLibraryMethod(val)` I see a really *long* type that I have absolutely no idea how to connect with my `Queries` type without using `any` as the value.

```
queryHookGenerator<QueryDefinition & Omit<Definition, "builderType">>(endpointName: string, endpointDefinition: QueryDefinition & Omit<Definition, "builderType">, axiosInstance: AxiosInstance): (args?: [queryArgs: ...] | undefined) => UseQueryResult<...>
import queryHookGenerator
```

Comment: Currently the code here isn’t a [mre] because we don’t have a definition of `some3rdPartyLibraryMethod` and anything it depends on.  Is your question about how to find an appropriate type assertion target instead of `any`?  Or are you asking how to do this without needing a type assertion at all?  If it’s the latter then we need the full definition of `some3rdPartyLibraryMethod` and anything it depends on. If it’s the former then you could provide a toy definition instead.  Either way please [edit] to make this something we can test in our IDEs without making possibly unfounded guesses.